# SQL Server to MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Friends,

I got a piece of code I need to migrate to PHP from ASP. I'm pretty good (or I think so...) in MySQL, but not so good at SQL Server, and the previous code has no documentation.

The query in SQL:

```
UPDATE tab1 SET colx = '0'
  FROM (SELECT tab1.id 
          FROM tab1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tab2 
                    ON tab1.col1 = tab2.col1 
                       AND tab2.col1 = tab1.col2 
                       AND tab1.col3 = tab2.col4
         WHERE tab2.col1 IS NULL 
               OR tab2.col4 IS NULL
        ) AS aux1 
        INNER JOIN tab1 ON aux1.id = tab1.id;
```

I don't know this sintax in MySQL. Any hint will be welcome.

Error message:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspond to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS aux1 INNER JOIN tab1 ON aux1.id = tab1.id'
```

Comment: Did you try the manual

Comment: The SQL looks straightforward. What error do you get when you use this in MySQL?

Comment: Nivas, only a sintax error. Strawberry, I've tried the manual, google...

Comment: @JairoFilho Please post the complete error message also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic in your query is a bit of a mess, I have distilled it to the following:

```
    UPDATE tab1
 LEFT JOIN tab2
        ON tab2.col1 = tab1.col1
       AND tab2.col1 = tab1.col2
       AND tab2.col4 = tab1.col3
       SET tab1.colx = '0'
     WHERE tab2.col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Gonna give this a try. BRB.

Comment: Arth, it works. But it's extremely slow. Both table has around 40000 rows each. I gonna need another solution, but thanks! I gonna need this stuff later.

Comment: @JairoFilho It should be fairly fast.. I can't think of a faster query. You probably need to work on your indexes, I suggest a composite index on (col1,col4) for tab2.

Comment: Thanks @Arth. I'll ask the DBA for index the table.